# Binding SortedList comparator to TableView comparator removes sort

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8, sortedlist

I have a SortedList that backs the data in a TableView. I want to sort the data by a particular column following queries to the database, but I want to maintain the TableView's interactive sorting functionality. My code:

```
sortedData = new SortedList<>(data, new TableSort(sortIndex));
sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(Table.comparatorProperty());
Table.setItems(sortedData);
```

However, when I bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView, my original comparator `TableSort` is ignored, and the data appears unsorted. If I choose not to bind comparators, my data is sorted correctly, but I can't perform interactive column sorting. How can I get the best of both worlds here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: use `sortedData.comparatorProperty().bindBidirectional(Table.comparatorProperty());` to bind the Comperator in both directions

Comment: I cannot do that with a TableView because its Comparator is a ReadOnlyObjectProperty

Comment: So you want to initially the elements to be sorted, then to  use the table's sort mechanism to sort the data? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Implement the Comperator Interface in the class of the items in your list.
Don't forget that you should also override the equals-Method (if compare(o1, o2) returns 0, o1.equals(o2) should return true)

Comment: @Sunflame Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @rollback I have already made my own Comparator; see `TableSort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to sort them initially before you put them in the table its quite simple.
I have a class `TestRow` that holds the information in the table, and implements the `Comparable` interface:

```
package stackoverflow;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class TestRow implements Comparable<TestRow> {

    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleStringProperty age;

    public TestRow(String name, String age) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.age = new SimpleStringProperty(age);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty ageProperty() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TestRow that) {
        return this.getName().compareTo(that.getName());
    }

}
```

Then in my controller i simply added two rows :

```
TestRow first = new TestRow("Steve", "20");
TestRow second = new TestRow("Mike", "22");
ObservableList<TestRow> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(first, second));
```

They you can simply call the `Collections.sort(data);`, then you can do the rest part, that you already have.

Comment: I will give this a try, though I am hoping for a simpler answer, as I have many fields, and they may change in the future

Comment: That is not a problem. because you want to sort them you need to know how to sort them, by field1, field2, or by multiple fields, so you have to write your own Comparator like you did but I think the god is more clear if you implement the`Comparable` inrerface and there you define how do you want to compare them

Comment: I saw you have written a custom comparator, so if you change your data you have to also update the comarator

Comment: I understand. If I go your route, I will use Comparable objects rather than a Comparator. My main concern is writing a property for each field, and manually fetching each field from my database rather than doing it independent of field names. It also adds another required edit target if fields are changed

Comment: If you prefer the comparator you can also use that this way: `Collections.sort (data, new MyComparator ());`

Comment: Used your last suggestion. Idk why I didn't think to do that in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Just call

```
table.getSortOrder().add(sortColumn);
```

where `sortColumn` is the `TableColumn` you want the initial sort to be by.

Comment: I tried this method originally, but using the built-in sort then requerying caused an IllegalStateException that crashed the program. Ostensibly, this was because unsorted data was added and violated the table comparator. Not entirely sure the reasons to be honest

Comment: @SeanScott That just sounds like you have something else wrong. What do you mean it "crashed the program"? Did you try to read the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450) and see what was wrong?

Comment: It was a series of IllegalStateExceptions referencing Thread.run(), etc. This call was happening within a Task

Comment: The error occurred on Table.setItems() only after it had been sorted using the GUI.

Comment: @SeanScott As I said, that is completely unrelated.

Comment: See above. Why would it work fine when unsorted but not otherwise?

Comment: @SeanScott It means you are manipulating the table data in a thread other than the FX Application Thread, which is a mistake whether or not it generates exceptions.

Comment: I can't use chat due to web restrictions, so I'll continue here. How would I avoid that? I'm doing a table update with a progress bar, hence my decision.

Comment: @SeanScott Wrap the updates in `Platform.runLater(...)`, or use the higher level [`javafx.concurrent` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html)